# Use css to change a property when another property is True

Tags: html, css

I want my input box to be visible when a slider is selected. My css code is:

CSS:

```
input:not(:checked) + .slider2:before {
   content:"Informal";
   .new {
     type: "visible";
   }

}
```

HTML:

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>
<input id="new" type="hidden">
```

...but it's not working. How can I have it so when `input:not(:checked) + .slider2:before` is True, set properties of `.new`? I am open to changing the display, not the input type.

Comment: This isn't valid CSS... how does your markup look like?

Comment: added my full code

Comment: There isn't any element of class `new`...

Comment: oops sorry. one sec

Comment: You cannot do this behavior in css alone..you need to do in javascript

Comment: @Martin I want it so it is invisible at startup. How can I do that in `html5`? I would be fine using that if it works.

Comment: note that classes start with a . in CSS referencing and id's start with a hash. Your code is telling CSS to edit a class called new but you only have an id called new.

Comment: for invisibility use CSS `display` or CSS `opacity` or suchlike. There's lots of options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the text box to be shown only when checkbox is not checked

you can do like this

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /*(sliderwidth*2 + left)*/
  width: 72px;
  height: 34px;
}

/*.switch input {display:none;}*/

.slider {
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.slider:before {
  /*Its the white box*/
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 32px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;

}
input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
input:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translateX(32px);
  /*must be same as slider width*/
}

input:checked + .slider:after {
   content:"Off";
} 
input:not(:checked) + .slider:before {
   content:"On";
}



#new {
     display:none;
}

input:not(:checked) + .slider:before {
   content:"Informal";  
}

input:not(:checked) + .slider + #new{
 display:block;
}

#new{
  position:absolute;
  right:20;
  bottom:0;
  margin-left:90px;
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
  <input id="new" type="text" value="whatever" >
</label>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: why isn't it straight up against the side?

Comment: I did not understand? what is not straight?

Comment: the input box isn't even with the switch